# Is it possible to get push notification data from fcm in simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios-simulator

First, sorry for my English.
I already know that simulator can't get push notification.
However, is it possible to get "just" data sent from FCM in simulator?

Comment: Just drag a payload file to simulator for testing. Real push notification should be received with Real Device

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.